# Android: ScrollView keeps wrapping the content instead of using layout_height

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

My ScrollView keeps wrapping the content inside of it instead of using the specified height I gave it.

Previewing the ScrollView in eclipse looks like this, and it's what I want:

[image]

But after inflating the ScrollView and using addView() to add it to a RelativeLayout, it wraps the content making it look like this:
[image]

Setting the layout_height to something small like 50dp has no effect.

This is the code used to add the ScrollView to my RelativeLayout:

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_profile_template, null);
overall_layout.addView(child);
```

Here is the xml for the ScrollView I'm inflating.

```
<ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/user_profile_popup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_popup_background"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:visibility="visible">

 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_wrapper"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

     <Button
            android:id="@+id/user_profile_add_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Add User"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/user_profile_add_button"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Username" />



      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/user_profile_username"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp">
    </ImageView>




      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/user_profile_about_me_title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:layout_below="@id/user_profile_pic"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:text="About Me" />



      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/user_profile_about_me_contents"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/user_profile_about_me_title"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:text="Contents of about me section
          Contents of about me section
          Contents of about me section
          Contents of about me section
          Contents of about me section
          Contents of about me section
          Contents of about me section
          Contents of about me section" />


      <ProgressBar
          android:id="@+id/user_profile_about_me_progress_bar"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/user_profile_about_me_title" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What's the LayoutParams you used to add your ScrollView?

Comment: @Leog I've added the 2 lines of code to my question that I am using to add the the ScrollView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you didn't pass the parent RelativeLayout as a root when you inflate your ScrollView, so it's width and height are not measured properly. Try the following change:

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_profile_template, null);
overall_layout.addView(child);
```

to:

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_profile_template, overall_layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `layout_marginBottom` on the ScrollView should do what you need.

EDIT: My bad, I didnt notice that you were programmatically adding the scrollview as a child to the overall_layout.
Set the height on the overall_layout in the following way:
`overall_layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, [your_height]))`

Comment: But that would change the height of the relative layout.  I want the height of the ScrollView to change. Also the relative layout that I'm adding this to is the overall layout of the activity.